# beta functions that don't reduce to known values

Tags: calculus, functions, special-functions

I am trying to convert $B(13/3, 11/3)$ into a Gamma function. I was hoping to reduce to $\Gamma(1/3 )$ for which there is a fixed value, but of course one reduces to $(6930/243) \Gamma(2/3)$ and the other $(630/81)\Gamma(2/3)$.

Can anyone advise?  Euler's reflection formula looks like it might work, but I can't get it.

Comment: Is not $B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ useful?

Comment: Does $\Gamma \big( \frac{1}{3} \big)\Gamma \big( \frac{2}{3} \big) = \frac{2}{{\sqrt 3 }}\pi$ help?

Comment: What do you mean "for which there is a fixed value"? $\Gamma(2/3)$ don't have a fixed value?

Comment: If you're to solve `beta(13/3,11/3) = x*gamma(1/3)`, I don't think x is a clean value. I poked around numerically and even used http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.00275185274485881302026172438785655395116461365860243600750703138335&lookup_type=simple to no avail. It is equal to `80/59049*Sqrt[3]*Pi` not sure if that helps

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}B\left(\frac{13}{3}, \frac{11}{3}\right)& = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{13}{3}) \cdot \Gamma(\frac{11}{3})}{\Gamma(\frac{13}{3} + \frac{11}{3})}
\\& = \frac{\Gamma(1 + \frac{10}{3}) \cdot \Gamma(1 + \frac{8}{3})}{\Gamma(\frac{24}{3})}
\\& = \frac{\Gamma(1 + \frac{10}{3})\cdot \Gamma(1 + \frac{8}{3})}{\Gamma(8)}
\\&= \frac{\frac{10}{3}\Gamma(\frac{10}{3})\cdot \frac83\Gamma(\frac{8}{3})}{7!}\\&= \frac{\frac{10}{3}\Gamma(1 + \frac{7}{3}) + \frac83\Gamma(1 + \frac{5}{3})}{5040} 
 \\&= \frac{\frac{10}{3}\cdot \frac73\Gamma(\frac{7}{3}) \cdot\frac83\cdot \frac53\Gamma(\frac{5}{3})}{5040}  
 \\&= \frac{\frac{10}{3}\cdot \frac73\Gamma(1 + \frac{4}{3}) \cdot \frac83\cdot \frac53\Gamma(1 + \frac{2}{3})}{5040}  
  \\&= \frac{\frac{10}{3}\cdot \frac43 \frac73\Gamma(\frac{4}{3}) \cdot \frac83\cdot \frac53\cdot \frac23\Gamma( \frac{2}{3})}{5040} 
\\&= \frac{\frac{10}{3}\cdot \frac43 \cdot\frac73\Gamma(1 + \frac{1}{3}) \cdot \frac83\cdot \frac53\cdot \frac23\Gamma( \frac{2}{3})}{5040} 
\\&= \frac{\frac{10}{3}\cdot \frac43 \cdot\frac73\cdot\frac13\Gamma(\frac{1}{3}) \cdot \frac83\cdot \frac53\cdot \frac23\Gamma( \frac{2}{3})}{5040}\end{align}$$

*Now put the value of $\Gamma(\frac13) \cdot \Gamma(\frac23) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\pi$ and you will be done!*

- Gamma-beta relationship has been used in the first step.
- In the further steps, I've used the result $\Gamma( 1+ n) = n\Gamma(n)$

Comment: Aah. Of course . Many thanks